# How to resume a Kotlin Coroutine Continuation in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am adding Kotlin code to a Java project. I created a Kotlin suspend function with `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

```
suspend fun someSuspendFunction = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean>{ continuation ->
     someJavaObject.someSuspendFunctionContinuation = continuation
}
```

I need `someSuspendFunction` to resume by some logic done in `someJavaObject` so I declare a field in `someJavaObject` to store the continuation for later use.

```
CancellableContinuation<Boolean> someSuspendFunctionContinuation;
```

However, when I want to resume it, I can't find a proper method to call. In Kotlin I can simply call `continuation.resume(true)`. I looked into the definition of `resume()` and found it called `resumeWith(Result.success(value))`. So I tried to write this in Java:

```
someSuspendFunctionContinuation.resumeWith(Result.Companion.success(true))
```

which gives this error: `'success(java.lang.Boolean)' has private access in 'kotlin.Result.Companion'`

So I tried to construct `Result` directly

```
someSuspendFunctionContinuation.resumeWith(new Result(true));
```

This gives me : `Expected 0 arguments but found 1`

Is it possible to construct a `Result` with value to reusme a coroutine continuation in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Result` object using reflection:

```java
public void resume() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    var successMethod = Result.Companion.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("success", Object.class);
    successMethod.setAccessible(true);

    someSuspendFunctionContinuation.resumeWith(successMethod.invoke(Result.Companion, true));
}
```

But I think it is better to just create yourself a very small util in Kotlin for using it in Java:

```kotlin
fun <T> resumeContinuationWithSuccess(cont: Continuation<T>, value: T) {
    cont.resumeWith(Result.success(value))
}
```

```java
public void resume() {
    SuspendUtils.resumeContinuationWithSuccess(someSuspendFunctionContinuation, true);
}
```